# Prove that the following is a base for $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given the following set of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$

$v_i = (a_{i1}, a_{i2}, ..., a_{in})$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$

and we know that $a_{ij} \leq 0$ whenever $i \neq j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} >0$

I'm supposed to prove that it's a base for $\mathbb R^n$

However, I have no idea where to begin. I can prove it for $\mathbb R^2$ proving the determinant of the matrix that has each vector as a row is nonzero, but I have no clue on how to prove it in the general case

I could try to get a formula for each of the diagonal entries in the triangulated nxn matrix, but it seems like a lot of work and I don't even know if that'll lead somewhere

Any hints on how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, notice that if you multiply one vector by a positive number and add it to another, the result still will have the property that the sum of all coordinates is positive.
2. Do the [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) of the matrix you mentioned(let us call it $M$). Just start with the top and go down, you will see each time you are doing the procedure from step 1 and $a_{ii}>0$; $a_{ij}<0$ for $i \ne j$ on each step.
3. In the end, you get an upper triangular matrix with positive entries on the diagonal, so $\det(M)>0$ (which means that vectors are linearly independent, so they form a basis)

Answer (score 3):

This may be nuking a mosquito, but the vectors are linearly independent since $$A= [v_1 \,\,\lvert \,\,\cdots \,\,\rvert \,\,v_n]$$ is invertible by Gershgorin’s circle theorem.

Comment: Yeah I definitely have never heard of that lmao

Comment: Easier: prove that if $0 \neq x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $Ax \neq 0$. Specifically, if $x\in \mathbb R^n$ is such that $x_i \neq 0$ then $(Ax)_i\neq 0$.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try that

Comment: Came back to say my answer from last night was a bit incomplete (sorry, I was on mobile). When $0 \neq x \in \mathbb R^n$, you should find the index $i$ so that $\lvert x_i\rvert = \max_{1\le k \le n} \lvert x_k \vert$; it is this $i$ which will satisfy $(Ax)_i \neq 0$.